# Can I create a simple Talend Job using its Java Source Code?

Tags: talend

can we generate a Talend Job through its Java code? For the sake of simplicity consider a simple Talend Job without any context variables for different environments and other complications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java code for a job is generated by the Studio, but there is no reverse operation consisting in generating a job from its corresponding Java code.
So, the short answer is "**No, you can't**".

You may consider to generate other files such as job.properties and job.item which contain the configuration for each component used by a job, but I'm afraid it could be very hazardous and at least a very long trip to try to do that.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks anyway!!